Solving $\int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2}dx$
I ran into this problem from the 2016 MIT Integration Bee Qualifier:
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2}dx=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_0^ax^3e^{-x^2}dx$$
I proceeded by calculating the indefinite integral
$$I:=\int x^3e^{-x^2}dx=\int x^2e^{-x^2}xdx$$
From here I let $u=x^2 \implies 2xdx=du$ and performed integration by parts one time:
$$I=\frac12\int ue^{-u}=\frac12(-ue^{-u}-e^{-u})+C=-\frac12 e^{-}(u+1)+C=-\frac12 e^{-x^2}(1+x^2)+C$$
Therefore we can get to the original integrals solution:
$$I=-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[ e^{-x^2}(1+x^2) \right]^a_0 =-\frac{1}{2}\lim_{a\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^2+1}{e^{a^2}}-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$
I am looking for alternative solutions. Thanks

@whatamidoing thanks, I've gone ahead and added that in.

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2}dx=-\frac d{da} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}x\ dx \ \bigg|{a=1}
= -\frac d{da}\frac1{2a} \bigg|{a=1}=\frac12
$$

@Quanto what is this technique called?

differentiation under integral sign

Lebnitz Rule - (Differentiation Under an Integral Sign).

I had two answers here, but realized a third that I like most. I posted it at the cited duplicate question.

This is a much quicker solution that involves the Gamma function. Recall:
$$\Gamma(a)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{a-1}e^{-x}dx,\forall a>0$$
Let us use the substitution $x^2=u \implies xdx=\frac{du}{2}$
This gives the following:
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}ue^{-u}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}u^{2-1}e^{-u}du=$$
$$\frac12\Gamma(2)=\frac12(1!)=\color{blue}{\frac12}$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} x^3 e^{-x^2} d x&=-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 d\left(e^{-x^2}\right) \\
& =-\frac{1}{2}\left(\left[x^2 e^{-x^2}\right]_0^{\infty}-\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} d\left(x^2\right)\right) \\
& =-\frac{1}{2}\left[e^{-x^2}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

You know that when $p(x)$ is a polynomial, then differentiating $p(x)e^{-x^2}$ gives $$\left[p'(x)-2xp(x)\right]e^{-x^2}$$
Can $p'(x)-2xp(x)=x^3$?

$p$ would have to be quadratic, leading coefficient $-\frac12$.
The linear term would have to be $0$ (considering when you let $x=0$).
Deduce that the constant term would have to be $-\frac12$. And it all works.

So $\int x^3e^{-x^2}\,dx=\left(-\frac12x^2-\frac12\right)e^{-x^2}+C$. And then "from $0$ to $\infty$" gives $\frac12$.

A boring alternative solution:
You used a substitution, and then integration by parts once. But what if you start out with integration by parts?
$$
\begin{align}
\int x^3e^{-x^2}\,dx
&=\int -\frac12x^2\left(-2xe^{-x^2}\right)\,dx\\
&=-\frac12x^2e^{-x^2}+\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx\\
&=-\frac12x^2e^{-x^2}-\frac12e^{-x^2}+C
\end{align}
$$
And "from $0$ to $\infty$" gives $\frac12$.

Here's the generalized version,
Consider;
$$I(n)=\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x^2}dx$$
$$x^2=t \implies 2x\,dx=dt \implies xdx=\frac{1}{2}\,dt\implies x=\left(t\right)^\frac12$$
$$I(n)=\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x^2}x\,dx\implies\int_0^{\infty}\left(t\right)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{-t} \frac{1}{2}\,dt$$
$$I(n)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}t^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{-t}\,dt$$
Now using the Gamma function;
$$\Gamma_n=\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,dx\implies n \to \frac{n+1}{2}\implies \Gamma_{\frac{n+1}{2}}=\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{n-1}{2}}e^{-x}\,dx $$
$$\boxed{I(n)=\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\Gamma_\left({\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)}{2}}$$
Your integral is; $n=3$
$$I(3)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_\left({\frac{3+1}{2}}\right)=\frac12$$

$$\Gamma_n = \int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,dx= (n-1)!\implies \Gamma_2 = 1$$

Furthermore,
$$x \to kx\implies dx=k\,dx$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\Gamma_\left({\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)}{2}\implies\int_0^{\infty}(kx)^ne^{-(kx)^2}kdx=\frac{\Gamma_\left({\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)}{2}$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}(kx)^ne^{-(kx)^2}kdx=\frac{\Gamma_\left({\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)}{2}\implies \boxed{I(n,k)=\int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-k^2x^2}dx=\frac{\Gamma_\left({\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)}{2k^{n+1}}}$$

@YvesDaoust thanks that makes it much simpler
